# django nested serializer and ViewSet

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a problem with nested serializer and ViewSet

My models are like this and their relationships are quite clear

> This classse have Nested relationships with each other

```
class Sim(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   subject = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)
   grade = models.ManyToManyField(Grade)

class Exercise(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   sim = models.OneToOneField(Sim,related_name='sims', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Result(models.Model):
   is_example = models.BooleanField(null=False)
   exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, 
       default=None)
class Parameter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, 
        default=None)

class ExerciseData(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    parameter = models.ForeignKey(Parameter, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, 
        null=True, default=None)
    result = models.ForeignKey(Result, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, 
        default=None)
```

> I want to build a ExerciseSerializer like this

```
class ExerciseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parameters = ParameterSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    exercisedatas = ExerciseDataSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    sims = SimSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
       model = models.Exercise
       fields = ['name', 'id', 'parameters', 'exercisedatas','sims']

    extra_kwargs = {
        'id': {'read_only': True},
    }

class SimSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    grade = GradeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    subject = SubjectSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Sim
        fields = ['name', 'subject', 'grade', 'id']

    extra_kwargs = {
        'id': {'read_only': True},
    }

class ParameterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Parameter
        fields = ['name', 'id']

    extra_kwargs = {
        'id': {'read_only': True},
    }

class ResultSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Result
        fields = ['is_example', 'id']

    extra_kwargs = {
        'id': {'read_only': True},
    }

class ExerciseDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parameter_set = ParameterSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    result_set = ResultSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
       model = ExerciseData
       fields = ['value', 'id', 'parameter_set', 'result_set']

    extra_kwargs = {
        'id': {'read_only': True},
    }
```

> And my viewsets is created Like :

```
class ExerciseViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.ExerciseSerializer
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    queryset = models.Exercise.objects.all()

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        queryset = play_filtering_form(queryset, self.request.query_params)
        return queryset
```

I do not receive the desired output

> Output

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "تمرین",
            "id": 1
        }
]
```

}

**I do not receive the three items of parameters and exercisedatas and sims**

Comment: I didn't understand your question very much, you're trying to get all the exercises?

Comment: @Omar yes, i'm trying to get all the exercises

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check your models and serializers code assuming they're correct, but in your viewset you could use a simpler way by using generic views.

Try the following view class:

```
class ExerciseViewset(generics.ListAPIView):
    # form its name, ListAPIView do one action which is GET for list of results
    serializer_class = serializers.ExerciseSerializer
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    queryset = models.Exercise.objects.all()
```

If you want to customize your query result, you can override the **get_queryset** method like so:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    # you can use self.queryset or models.Exercise.objects.filter(any filter)
    return self.queryset.filter(some filtering)
```

A quick summary about generic views:

> **generics.ListAPIView**: Allows GET only used for listing many results

> **generics.RetrieveAPIView**: Allows GET only, used for retrieving specific result using lookup_field, by default: **pk** (for example in your urls.py: exercise/<int:pk>/)

> **generics.CreateAPIView**: Allows POST only

> **generics.UpdateAPIView**: Allows PUT/Patch only

> **generics.DestroyAPIView**: Allows DELETE only

> **There are great combinations like**: generics.ListCreateAPIView (POST, GET),
> generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView (GET, PUT/PATCH)...

Documentation link:
[DRF generic views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/)